# Aura component without any DOM element?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, scalability, aura.js

On the Aura.js '[Getting Started](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Aaurajs.com%2Fgetting-started%2F&oq=cache%3Aaurajs.com%2Fgetting-started%2F&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.1292j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)' page (which is down at the moment, so that's a Google cache link) it says the following:

> The other way to start components on application start is to
>   explicitly pass a list to the app.start method. Example:
>
> ```
> `app.start([{ name: 'hello', options: { el: '#hello' } }]);`
> ```
>
> All listed components MUST have at least the name and options.el
>   defined, where name is the name of the component to start and
>   options.el is a DOM selector to target the DOM Element that will be
>   the root of your component.

So from that it seems like Aura requires that every module/component MUST have an associated DOM element. Is that correct?

In my app I'd like to have some modules which are purely for running long background calculations which shouldn't be associated with any DOM element. They emit their computed results to other modules which deal with displaying.

I love the philosophy behind Aura.js (mediator/modules + MVC) but I don't really want to hack around it too much. Any insights would really be appreciated. Maybe I've misinterpreted something? Maybe there's a better framework for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component requires an associated DOM element, but it doesn't require that the DOM element be visible on the page, just accessible within the DOM. You could create a place to put your invisible components like this:

```
$("body").append('<div id="invisbleComponents" style="display:none"></div>');
```

Then you can create a method to start your components and dump them in your invisible div automatically:

```
var startComponent = function(c) {
    $('<div data-aura-component="' + c + '" id="' + c + 'Options"></div>').appendTo("#invisibleComponents);
    app.start([{ name: c, options: { el: '#' + c + 'Options' } }]);
};
```

So to start a component called "myComponent" you just make a call:

```
startComponent('myComponent');
```

Comment: Thanks Steve - is this a bit hacky though? Why do I need a DOM element for modules that are just performing large calculations?

Comment: Joe, the way Aura works, the DOM element is necessary because Aura uses the DOM to define the component's scope. This way, nested components understand their relationship with their parents, etc. The power gained from this is well worth having to write three lines of code to 'hack' anonymous components into the DOM.

Comment: Oh that's interesting, I had no idea - where did you learn about that? 'Getting started' didn't mention anything about scope. I thought it was purely pub/sub and each module was completely independent.

Comment: It's in the page you posted, there's a whole section on 'nesting' components.

Comment: Aha, I read that but didn't realise Aura revolved around this concept. Thanks for your help mate